# I don't like a dog who barks - "I don't like barking dogs in general" or "There is a dog that barks who I don't like"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

I wonder whether the following examples can have two meanings:

> talking about something in general

> talking about a specific something.

Do you guys agree?

**Example 1:**

> I don't like a dog.

I think it can be two different meanings: "I don't like dogs in general" or "There is a dog I don't like."

**Example 2:**

> I don't like a dog who barks.

I think it can be two different meanings: "I don't like dogs who bark in general" or "There is a dog that barks who I don't like."

Comment: Rule: like, dislike, hate, love etc. + plural countable noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your examples is idiomatic.

English speakers would not use these constructions, so the question doesn't really arise.

If you dislike dogs, you would say: **I don't like dogs (plural)**

If you dislike a particular dog, you would say: **I don't like the/this/that dog.**

Equally, we don't talk about **a dog who..**. It's **a dog that..**

Even so, we wouldn't say, **I don't like a dog that barks.** It's grammatically correct but not natural.

The natural construction is: **I don't like barking dogs.** or **I don't like dogs that bark.**

You can make statements such as: **I don't like a policeman in a dirty uniform**, meaning that you disapprove of any policeman in a dirty uniform.

If it were a particular policeman, you would say **...the policeman...**

There isn't really much room for ambiguity.

Comment: Well done. Very clear.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. However, I saw this online: "I don't like a girl who puts on lots of makeup." This means "girls who put on lots of makeup in general." Why is there a use case like this? Is it dependant on the context?

Comment: Sorry for asking many questions. But I came up with a scenario that "I don't like a dog that barks." can make sense. For example, A says, "I love animals, but I don't like a dog that barks. It was a stray dog coming to my backyard barking all night." Does the sentence make sense in this context?

Comment: Yes, it does in that context.

Comment: Using “who” to refer to a dog is pretty common; the whole “a blank who/that whatever” construction is kind of unusual (feels dated to me?), but I don’t see how that or who would be better. Nor do I see why the policeman example or the girl example is superior to the dog example—it’s a dated (I think?) construction, but not an “unnatural” one, nor one that’s better or worse depending on the subject so far as I know.

Comment: @KRyan Yup. I have a lot of dogs and they are all **who** dogs. But a learner should know that you get no marks for saying: **That is the dog who bit me**.  For the rest, it's good always to hear other informed opinions!